# What do the icons in the ability descriptions mean?

Tags: final-fantasy-7-rebirth

When using abilities such as Cloud's 'Focused Thrust' at the bottom of the Commands menu is the description which includes the small rectangle icon denoting that the skill will fill a synergy block.

[image: ability icons]

However I have noticed some skills have other icons and I can't find out what they mean. What does this lightning icon mean for example?

Is there a list of these icons and what they mean?

Comment: I think it has something to do with moves that can be used airborne, but doesn’t seem to be really consistent. The icon started showing up after hitting party level 3 and the abilities also had text had, like “more potent while airborne” or “can be used airborne”

Comment: Yeah, I have postulated that they might be denoting a 'gap closer', so using the ability will move the character to the target, but I haven't tested the hypothesis